# java service vs Rules engine implementation

Tags: java, rule-engine

I am confused choosing between java service and IBM Rules Designer. I am aware of the fact that we should use Rules Engine for less development effort and whenever the business requirements are subject to change frequently. But I have requirements which can be developed either using java or Rules Engine. Considering the performance, maintenance cost,re usability and other factors in long term which is the best option to implement? what are the ideal cases when to use this either of them?

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Soft_Coding

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is a bit objective.

For me, if certain "changeable logic" is related routine work (e.g. Such settings are required when introducing a new user to system, or a new product to be sold etc), I will consider using rule engine (or other "soft coding" skill as mentioned in the comment in OP).  As we should not require deploying the application again just because we need to do such routine job.

However, if some logic is related to requirement and such change is not triggered by routine job, I am inclined to write it in code.